# Powershell Set-Content corrupts file formatting after -Replace is used

Tags: file, powershell, text

Bond.out file example (looking to replace what is highlighted):

[image]

Out.csv file (data to be used):

[image]

Code:

```
#set paths up
$filepath= 'C:\folder\path\bond.out'
$filepath2= 'C:\folder\path\temp.txt'
$Ticklist='C:\folder\path\tick.txt'
$ratelist='C:\folder\path\rate.txt'

#Import needed data from an excel file which creates and array
$csv = Import-CSV C:\folder\path\RateIDTable.csv | Where { $_.'Rate' -ne "" } | Export-Csv C:\folder\path\out.csv -NoTypeInformation
$bond = Import-CSV C:\folder\path\out.csv | select -Property TickerID, Rate

#Put array from Excel file into two text files
$Tick = $bond | foreach-object {$_.TickerID} | set-content $Ticklist
$replace = $bond | foreach-object {$_.rate} | set-content $Ratelist

#Create two separate arrays from the new text files
$Tickdata = (Get-content $Ticklist ) -join ','
 foreach ($t in $Tickdata)
  {
  $t = $t -split(",")
  $First = $t[0]}

$Ratedata = (Get-content $Ratelist ) -join ','
 foreach ($r in $Ratedata)
  {
  $r = $r -split(",")
  $First = $r[0]}  

#Get main file to search (bond.out) and search for the word that is in the first line from "t" array file
$data = Select-String $filepath -pattern $t[0] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
$data

#Once found, split the line, replace the rate on the 3rd line with the rate in the first line from the "r" array file, the put the line back to together
$split=$data.split("{|}")
$split[3]=$r[0]
$join = $split -join "|"
$join

#Put the updated line back into the "bond.out" file from whence it came
(get-content $filepath) -replace($data,$join) | set-content $filepath

#computer says no :(
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see, it actually replaces the rate and puts it all back like I need it to. But that last line doesn't seem to work. Instead I get the file back like so:

[image]

It appears as though it is repeating the same line from the $join parameter and adding letters to the beginning of each iteration.

I believe it has something to do with the '|' at the end of the line, and remember reading something about marking the beginning and end of lines some time ago, but can't find it anywhere.

Comment: `|` is a special character for regular expressions, which used by `-replace` operator.

Comment: This gave me the clue I needed! Thanks for that. New code posted below

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea. Instead of using regular expressions ...

The `Import-Csv` command has a `-Delimiter` parameter. Can you just import `bond.out` as a "CSV" (but with a pipe delimiter), and update it just like you would a CSV file?

#### Pseudo-code

```
### Convert bond.out to objects
$BondOut = Import-Csv -Delimiter '|' -Path $FilePath

### Get the line you want to update
$LineToUpdate = $BondOut.Where({ $PSItem.TickerID -eq 'BBG0019K2QZ5' })

### Update the Rate property from your source (out.csv)
$LineToUpdate.Rate = $SomeSource.Rate

### Export the modified objects to a new bond.out.modified file
$BondOut | Export-Csv -Delimiter '|' -Path 'bond.out.modified' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thanks for the great idea, but unfortunately the start of the file contains lines without pipes in them and some contain dates (IE: 02/10/17), so this fails on me.

Comment: @Chris That makes sense. Figured it was worth a shot. :)

Answer (score 0):

As per PetSerAI's clue:

```
#set paths up
$filepath= 'C:\folder\path\bond.out'
$filepath2= 'C:\folder\path\temp.txt'
$Ticklist='C:\folder\path\tick.txt'
$ratelist='C:\folder\path\rate.txt'

#Import needed data from an excel file which creates and array
$csv = Import-CSV C:\folder\path\RateIDTable.csv | Where { $_.'Rate' -ne "" } | Export-Csv C:\folder\path\out.csv -NoTypeInformation
$bond = Import-CSV C:\folder\path\out.csv | select -Property TickerID, Rate

#Put array from Excel file into two text files
$Tick = $bond | foreach-object {$_.TickerID} | set-content $Ticklist
$replace = $bond | foreach-object {$_.rate} | set-content $Ratelist

#Create two separate arrays from the new text files
$Tickdata = (Get-content $Ticklist ) -join ','
 foreach ($t in $Tickdata)
  {
  $t = $t -split(",")
}

$Ratedata = (Get-content $Ratelist ) -join ','
 foreach ($r in $Ratedata)
  {
  $r = $r -split(",")
}  

#Get main file to search (bond.out) and search for the word that is in the first line from "t" array file

###Replace all pipes with a comma

(get-content $filepath) -replace('\|', ',') | set-content $filepath
$data = Select-String $filepath -pattern $t[0] | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Line
$data

#Once found, split the line, replace the rate on the 3rd line with the rate in the first line from the "r" array file, the put the line back to together
$split=$data.split("{,}")
$split[3]=$r[0]
$join = $split -join ","

#Put the updated line back into the "bond.out" file from whence it came

###change all commas back to pipes

(get-content $filepath) -replace($data,$j) | set-content $filepath
(get-content $filepath) -replace(',', '|') | set-content $filepath
#computer says yay :D
```